# How increment and decrement "arithmetic operations" can be performed in any one of the registers in 8085?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, microprocessors, 8085

AFAIK, arithmetic and logical operations are performed with the contents of the accumulator , and the results are stored in the accumulator.
Then how increment and decrement arithmetic operations can be performed in any one of the registers or in a memory location?

Comment: In many architectures the line between "accumulator" and "general purpose register" is quite blurred or even non-existent. With 8085 it just so happens that the architecture supports INC/DEC on registers other than A, but why shouldn't it ? What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: @PaulR; My question is specific to 8085 architecture.

Comment: Down voters, leave your comments. It should be appreciated.

Comment: @PaulR; Because it is arithmetic operation and it should be performed on accumulator.

Comment: What makes you think that ? Most modern CPUs support ALU operations on any general purpose register - it's only some older CPUs (and the 8085 is very, very ancient) that make an arbitrary distinction between accumulators and registers. Why does this bother you ? The architecture is what it is - you certainly can't change it, and if it's not causing you any specific problem then why worry ?

Comment: @PaulR; Actually I am verifying my ALP programs on 8085 ( after hand-ssembling). I read its hardware and programming model in which it is clearly specified that all the arithmetic and logical operations are performed on accumulator. While writing assembly programs, increment/decrement operations are performed on any register and that makes me to think about that.

Comment: The 8085 documentation does describe the accumulator as the place to do "arithmetic and logical operations" but doesn't exclude some operations from the other registers. In fact, the other registers are described as allowing use in pairs as address (pointers). Operations of increment and decrement are essential for pointer operations, so it only makes sense that some arithmetic is allowed on these registers, if for no other reason.

Comment: @dwelch; Not much clear.

Comment: very clear, see below.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question but I would have. You are making an assumption that you don't justify or even state in so many words: that arithmetic operations _should_ be performed _only_ in the accumulator. Increment and decrement **can** be performed in other registers because the ISA designers decided to add that capability.

Comment: @JoeHass; Isn't increment and decrement operation are arithmetic and should be performed in accumulator like other arithmetic operations?

Comment: No, there is no reason to assume that increment and decrement should **only** be done in the accumulator. Memory pointers need to be incremented and decremented very often and there's no reason they should be moved through the accumulator to do that. Whatever makes the architecture more efficient, that's what _should_ be done.

Answer (score 1):

From the mcs 80/85 users manual, Intel very clearly indicates what registers the instructions can use.

```
DDD or SSS   REGISTER NAME
111              A
000              B
001              C 
010              D
011              E 
100              H 
101              L
```

...

```
INR r  (Increment Register)
(r) <- r + 1
The content of register r is increment by one.  Note: All condition flags except CY are affected
[00DDD100] (encoding)
Cycles: 1
States: 4(8085), 5 (8080)
Addressing: register
Flags: Z,S,P,AC
```

What part is not clear?

All somewhat clustered are the DCR r, INR r, DCR m, INX rp, DCX rp, and a number of other instructions that are not limited specifically to the accumulator.

Google 205775-002 to find pdf copies of the Intel manual.  If you don't have one then you should get one before moving forward with any more 8080/85 assembly language.

Comment: Off course, I have a copy to hand assemble the programs in assembly language :)